# How to add having to entity query Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query

Tags: 8, database

I need to alter the query in ***getEntityIds*** method in [`PathAliasListBuilder`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path%21src%21PathAliasListBuilder.php/class/PathAliasListBuilder/8.8.x) i need only to get only paths with multiple path system:

The sql select should be like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `path_alias`
GROUP BY `path`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

i manage to add group by:

```
$query->groupBy('path');
```

But i didn't find anyway to add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

I have found this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206444/how-to-use-conditions-on-a-count-expression#answer-206448) how to add having to ***Select*** but nothing how to **Query**?